# Is the squared Cohen's $f$ the same as Cohen's $f^2$?

Tags: regression, interaction, terminology, statistical-power, cohens-d

**Question**

Is the squared version of Cohen's $f$ the same as Cohen's $f^2$? Or do they only share the same letter by coincidence?

**Explanation**

At first, I wondered if one can simply square Cohen's $f$ to obtain the Cohen's $f^2$. For example, papers often report Cohen's $d$, but power analyses (for regression) often require $f^2$ as estimate of the effect size. According to [this source](https://www.escal.site/), it is possible to convert Cohen's $d$ to $f$ with the following formula :

$f = d/2$

Therefore, if one were to square the resulting $f$, would one be able to use this value as estimated effect size in a power analysis?

I would think that you cannot do that and that they are not related because they are part of different families and use different calculations ($f^2$ is part of the correlation family, while $f$ is part of the difference family). I was speaking with a statistician friend recently who was unsure himself because they're both related to regression under the hood. So I just wanted to confirm this with the community?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The effect size index $f^2$ is defined by Cohen as $\frac{R^2}{1-R^2}$ in a regression model where $R^2$ is the coefficient of determination (the % of variance explained by the model). Cohen emphasized the fact that is fundamentally identical to the $f$ index, hence you can take the square root of $f^2$ to get your estimate for $f$ (*Statistical Power Analysis for the behavioral Sciences*, 2nd ed., Lawrence Erlbaum Associates, 1988; §9.2, p. 410). It is just easier to work with a squared index when you already work with squared correlation values.

Sometimes, it is also computed as $\frac{\eta^2}{1-\eta^2}$ or $\frac{\eta_\text{partial}^2}{1-\eta_\text{partial}^2}$, especially when the authors focus on ANOVA. This is discussed later in $9.2.1, but you will find the same explanation on the [UCLA website](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/effect-size-power/faqhow-is-effect-size-used-in-power-analysis/).

Comment: So, are you saying that it is possible and **correct** to convert a Cohen's _d_ to Cohen's _f2_ for power analysis purposes?

Comment: AFAICT, there's a general formula that: $f^2 = d^2/2k$, where $k$ is the number of groups in, e.g., a one-way ANOVA. I never used it in regression, but in this case I would simply use the $\eta^2$-based approach, since this is often reported as a measure of ES. Why do you need to convert Cohen's $d$ to $f$? What is your use case? (For power analysis in regression, you generally provide information about the variance and the expected difference in slopes and/or intercepts.)

Comment: Oh, very interesting, thank you. I've accepted your answer. I wonder if you shouldn't add part of this comment into your answer re the formula $f^2$ and $d^2$?

Comment: We're using a three-way moderated regression with group as predictor and two moderators. The primary interest is the effect of group and the original paper doesn't report effect sizes for us to use in power analysis. I was able to compute Cohen's $d$ based on reported means and SDs as this is the best estimate available for the group effect. So although it might not be a statistical error to use this approach, is it a logical/reasoning error? (trying to estimate a moderation effect based on a mean difference effect?)

Comment: Thanks! The above formula is already available via the link to the UCLA server I provided in my answer. I'm not familiar with effect size in moderation analysis. I would say your appraoch is ok ([David Kenny](http://davidakenny.net/cm/moderation.htm) recommends the use of Cohen's d indeed), although a significant interaction between moderator(s) and the predictor of interest may cimplicate things a bit. See also [Standardized Effect Sizes for Moderated Conditional Fixed Effects with Continuous Moderator Variables](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2017.00562/full).